# Error Element xpath cannot be located in parent view

Tags: odoo

Please, i need to customize fields to print from rapport of sale module, so I created a new module and installed it (odoo 12). I have created an XML file, but have this error:

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Element '<xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-condensed']//thead//tr">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `report_quotation_inherit_demo`
[view_id: 1603, xml_id: n/a, model: n/a, parent_id: 649]
None" while parsing None:5, near
<data inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
        <!-- Finds the first table with as class table table-condensed and gives the ability to modify it
         This will replace everything withing tr (including tr)-->
        <xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-condensed']//thead//tr" position="replace">
                    <tr style="background-color:lightgray;">
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                    </tr>
        </xpath>
        <!-- This will search for the 4'th td element (in the tbody with class sale_tbody) and will remove it. -->
        <!-- Important: if you would start with element 2, then do 3 and then do 4 you will see strange behaviour.
            The first statement would remove element 2 making all other elements move in numbering too. -->
        <xpath expr="//tbody[@class='sale_tbody']//tr//td[4]" position="replace">
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//tbody[@class='sale_tbody']//tr//td[3]" position="replace">
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//tbody[@class='sale_tbody']//tr//td[2]" position="replace">
        </xpath>
        </data>
```

Comment: Can you put the original view code to understand from where exactly you want to inherit template.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B9Ley4xaFHgyB9Xq10_nKwmgjXeG21tX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element xpath cannot be located in parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222227/element-xpath-cannot-be-located-in-parent-view)

Answer (score 1):

You can also define **xpath** like this:

```
 <xpath expr="//table//thead//tr[1]" position="replace">
```

From this, it is necessary to have only one table in that template and one **`thead`** in that table.

If there are multiple than you can define number like as I given example **`tr[1]`**